# itertools.repeat VS itertools.cycle

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

Is there any difference between `itertools.repeat(n)` and `itertools.cycle(n)`? As it seems, they produce the same output. Is one more efficient to use in a situation where I need an *infinite* loop of some element?

Comment: If you just need an infinite sequence of an element, use `repeat`, the answers below will explain the differences.

Comment: @JaredGoguen I concur.  The *repeat* version is clearer and faster.  It is the preferred approach.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply, `itertools.repeat` will repeat the given argument, and `itertools.cycle` will cycle over the given argument. Don't run this code, but for example:

```
from itertools import repeat, cycle

for i in repeat('abcd'): print(i)
# abcd, abcd, abcd, abcd, ...

for i in cycle('abcd'): print(i)
# a, b, c, d, a, b, c, d, ...
```

Comment: The example would be better if you used "abcd" as argument for the repeat function as well.

Answer (score 6):

These are equivalent but the first is clearer and a little faster:

```
it = repeat(x)
it = cycle([x])
```

However, *cycle* has the option of repeating entire sequences:

```
it = cycle(['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'])
```

And *repeat* has the option of setting a limit on the number of repetitions:

```
it = repeat(x, 5)         # Return five repetitions of x
```

Also, the intended use cases are different.

In particular, *repeat* was designed to provided a repeated argument to a mapped function:

```
it = imap(pow, repeat(2), range(10))
```

While *cycle* is intended for cyclic recurring behaviors.  Here is a Python 3 example that returns `1/1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 + ...`:

```
it = accumulate(map(operator.truediv, cycle([1, -1]), count(1, 2)))
```

The latter example shows how all the parts fit together the create an "iterator algebra".

Hope you found this to be illuminating :-)

Answer (score 2):

`itertools.cycle()` takes an *iterator*. You can't do, for example, `itertools.cycle(5)` - this will throw an error:

```
>>> itertools.cycle(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

`itertools.repeat()` will repeat the same element over and over again - it is *not* designed to iterate through the elements of an iterator. It is *very good* for returning the same object over and over again.

In other words, doing `itertools.repeat([1,2,3], 5)` does:

```
>>>>[i for i in itertools.repeat([1,2,3], 5)]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

while doing `itertools.cycle([1,2,3])` returns an infinite list that looks like `[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,...]` (or it least it would if you could fit it in memory somehow).

The difference is fairly profound.

Answer (score 2):

`itertools.repeat` *returns* the same object over and over again, and `itertools.cycle` *iterates* over the same object over and over again. So:

```
import itertools

# Warning: infinite loop ahead
for x in itertools.repeat([1, 2, 3]):
    print(x)
    # [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], ...

for x in itertools.cycle([1, 2, 3]):
    print(x)
    # 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ...
```

So if what you want is something that returns one object several times, use `itertools.repeat`; and if it's something that loops over some different object use `itertools.cycle`.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the itertools documents to know the difference.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> help(itertools.repeat)
Help on class repeat in module itertools:

class repeat(__builtin__.object)
 |  repeat(object [,times]) -> create an iterator which returns the object
 |  for the specified number of times.  If not specified, returns the object
 |  endlessly.
 |
...
...

>>> help(itertools.cycle)
Help on class cycle in module itertools:

class cycle(__builtin__.object)
 |  cycle(iterable) --> cycle object
 |
 |  Return elements from the iterable until it is exhausted.
 |  Then repeat the sequence indefinitely.
 |
```